# VB.NET - Inherits System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList doesn't call "Render" method

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, inheritance, drop-down-menu

I have the following code, and when I put a Control of this type on a WebForm, it does not throw the Exception as you would expect it to, instead a <SELECT> is nicely rendered.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Web.UI

<ToolboxData("<{0}:DropDownList runat=server></{0}:DropDownList>")> _
Public Class DropDownList
    Inherits System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList

    Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
        Throw New Exception("Hello World")
    End Sub

End Class
```

However, I have this code, and it works just fine (in that the Exception does get thrown):

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Web.UI

<ToolboxData("<{0}:TextBox runat=server></{0}:TextBox>")> _
Public Class TextBox
    Inherits System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox

    Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
        Throw New Exception("Hello World")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Have you tried overriding `CreateChildControls` too?

Comment: Unfortunately I need to create a sibling control, so I can't use this method

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely certain that you referenced the new class and not the standard asp.net one? That's the only reason I can think of that it wasn't called.

You might check the designer file to be absolutely certain. I have had numerous cases where I changed the control type in the source view, but the designer file was not updated until I went to the Design view and dirtied something.

Comment: I checked the designer file, and they do reference the custom control